# What does this symbol mean in my Unix command?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm doing some tutorial and I see this shell command:

```
find / -name foo 2>/dev/null
```

What does the last token do? Specifically, the `2`? I get that the `>` redirection will send the shell output to a file, but how does `find` get only the error message ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2>/dev/null` means to redirect stderr to /dev/null.  The `2` comes from the file descriptor for stderr; stdin is always `0`, stdout is always `1`, and stderr is always `2`.  The default source for output redirection is stdout, so `>/dev/null` has the same meaning as `1>/dev/null`.

By the way, that's a shell feature; it's not specific to `find`.